# As3 while loop adding child

Tags: actionscript-3, while-loop, children

So I am trying to create a instance for every point in this quiz I am making, I am trying to make it create a movieclip symbol for every point I have so naturally I tried using a while loop, but for some reason only one object is created.

```
var teiknFeilApe:MovieClip = new feilSvarape;
var teiknRettApe:MovieClip = new rettSvarape;
var rettX:Number = 225;
var feilX:Number = 225;
var rettY:Number = 105;
var feilY:Number = 160;

while(rettSvar > 0){

addChild(teiknRettApe);
teiknRettApe.x = rettX;
teiknRettApe.y = rettY;
teiknRettApe.width = 50;
teiknRettApe.height = 40;

rettX = rettX + 55; 

rettSvar = rettSvar - 1;
}
while(feilSvar > 0){

addChild(teiknFeilApe);
teiknFeilApe.x = feilX;
teiknFeilApe.y = feilY;
teiknFeilApe.width = 50;
teiknFeilApe.height = 40;

feilX = feilX +55;

feilSvar = feilSvar - 1;

}
```

So in the code "rettSvar" and "feilSvar" is a number variable added earlier that is working. The only problem with my code is that it is not creating an instance of a object for every "rettSvar" and "feilSvar", but only one object in total.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed my problem. I just put

```
var teiknFeilApe:MovieClip = new feilSvarape;
var teiknRettApe:MovieClip = new rettSvarape;
```

into the loops directly.

Comment: Nope that did not fix your problem at all. You might think it did but you did something else that fixed it.